# What hose is this? (2000 lexus es300 w/ 1mzfe VVT-i)

Tags: engine, lexus

Damn thing snapped while I was taking it off, no idea what it is and can't quite seem to find out on google for some reason.

[image]

It goes from the front valve cover to the intake.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a crankcase breather to me - just allows air (and oil vapours) in and out of the engine - it goes to the inlet inboard of the filter to prevent the vapours being released into the atmosphere.